# Is it assumed that you run mix deps.compile after updating config.exs?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've started using Elixir + Phoenix Framework and started incorporating the [addict](https://github.com/trenpixster/addict) library for user registration/authentication.

The docs for addict tell me to update the `config.exs` for the `:addict` app.

```
config :addict, not_logged_in_url: "/error",
                db: MyApp.MyRepo,
                user: MyApp.MyUser,
                    :
```

Replacing the db and user values did not take affect till I ran `mix deps.compile` for the addict code to pick up the configs.

Now my question is, is it assumed to run `mix deps.compile` when you make changes to `config.exs`?

The addict docs don't state this and for a newcomer like me, this isn't really obvious. I only realized this when I actually looked into addict's code and saw that it was being set at compile time via a module attribute (thus the necessity to run `mix deps.compile`).

Comment: To expand on this (after a little experimentation; I'm not entirely sure), `Application.get_env…` reading from config.exs seems not to pick up new values without recompiling, whether you do the `get_env` in a module attribute or inside a function that's called at run-time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28912658/6962 suggests you want a third-party lib if you need runtime config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to recompile dependencies only if they have compile time configuration. Compile time configuration as such is not very common, so you should ping the `addict` folks and ask them to have better instructions to what happens when someone configures `addict` after it was compiled. Or convince them to avoid the compile time configuration in the first place if they can.